# Improper insertions to sql db using jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, applet

The problem is that running a test code to insert data into the db using an applet to take the input. Once I insert the data and close the applet, the data in order, in the corresponding EMPLOYEE table in the db. But when re-launch the applet again and insert again, the data is inserted into the start of the table and not inserting sequentially.

I can't seem to understand the problem.

Here the corresponding code,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.sql.*;

public class Test extends Frame {
    TextField tf;
    Label l;
    Button b;
    int count=1;

    Test() {
        tf = new TextField();
        l = new Label("Enter Name");
        b = new Button("Join");
        tf.setBounds(100, 130, 100, 30);
        l.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 30);
        b.setBounds(100, 160, 100, 30);

        add(l);
        add(tf);
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                join(tf.getText());

            }
        });

        setSize(500, 500);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void join(String name) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hemesh-pc:1521:xe","system", "*****");

            Statement s = conn.createStatement();

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM EMPLOYEE");

            resultSet.next();

            System.out.println(resultSet.getInt("count(*)"));

            count = resultSet.getInt("count(*)")+1;

            String query = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES("+count+",'"+name+"')";

            int res = s.executeUpdate(query);

            System.out.println(res+"Row created");

            conn.commit();

            s.close();

            conn.close();
        }catch(Exception c){ 
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3BMj.jpg)

Comment: a) SQL Injection alert b) using `COUNT(*) + 1` instead of sequence c) `INSERT INTO` without explicit column list d) storing object in `SYSTEM` schema. This is only SQL review.

Comment: e) `SELECT * FROM employee` without explicit `ORDER  BY EID`.

Comment: Have you heard of ["auto incrementing field types"?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) Also, note that the order of the entries is irrelevant as the database could return the values in a different order when using the same query, unless you specify the order otherwise

Comment: [Learn about and use `PreparedStatement`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: AWT is out-of-date. Consider using Swing or JavaFX instead, you'll get better support and while you're at it, learn and understand the importance of layout managers